# randomize image gallery on load/selection

Tags: javascript, jquery

This is my first question, so my apologies for any formatting issues, omissions by ignorance, or over-explaining. I'm almost totally new to Javascript, and after a day of trying to modify this I decided to ask for help.

Currently: I have an unordered list that is used as a selector to bring up a gallery associated with it. What I'm attempting to do is modify the code below to make the images load in random order, instead of the default (loading by order of last added). I've been attempting to use the Fisher Yates method, but I'm either implementing it wrong, or just confused. Any help would be appreciated and thanks for taking the time to read this.

```
 $('#artist-list li').click(function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    var artist = $(this).attr('data-artist');

    // Highlight selected menu item
    $('#artist-list li').removeClass('active');
    $(this).addClass('active');

    // Show selected artist bio
    $('.artist-bio, .artist-image').hide();
    $('#artist-'+artist+', #artist-image-'+artist).show();

    $('#image-list li').not('.primary').hide();
    $('#image-list li.'+artist).show().children('a').attr('rel', artist);
}); // End click

$('#artist-list.departments li').click(function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    var artist = $(this).attr('data-dept');

    // Highlight selected menu item
    $('#artist-list li').removeClass('active');
    $(this).addClass('active');

    // Show selected artist bio
    $('.artist-bio, .artist-image').hide();
    $('#artist-'+artist+', #artist-image-'+artist).show();

    $('#image-list li').not('.primary').hide();
    $('#image-list li.'+artist).show().children('a').attr('rel', artist);
}); // End click
```

Comment: Can you post your attempted code at making the artist list generate in random order?  You are asking a question about helping you sort the list, but then you only show code about clicking to activate a list item... seems inconsistent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found this little useful plugin that could shuffle the lists for you:

```
(function($){

    $.fn.shuffle = function() {

        var allElems = this.get(),
            getRandom = function(max) {
                return Math.floor(Math.random() * max);
            },
            shuffled = $.map(allElems, function(){
                var random = getRandom(allElems.length),
                    randEl = $(allElems[random]).clone(true)[0];
                allElems.splice(random, 1);
                return randEl;
           });

        this.each(function(i){
            $(this).replaceWith($(shuffled[i]));
        });

        return $(shuffled);

    };

})(jQuery);
```

And to do it on a list, like this:

```
<ul id="gallery">
    <li>1</li>
    <li>2</li>
    <li>3</li>
    <li>4</li>
    <li>5</li>
</ul>
```

Call it:

```
$('#gallery li').shuffle();
```

jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/hescano/4XFQr/

Source: http://css-tricks.com/snippets/jquery/shuffle-dom-elements/

Comment: Good idea, I'm still confused a little on how to modify the original code, but using that works for my purpose and I can research more on my own to figure out the particulars. Thanks for the quick response.